# how to know which canvas ondraw bitmap is touched.?

Tags: android, canvas

I have drawn two Bitmap  in ondraw of a view extending class.I want to start two different activity if i touch on any bitmap. like if i touch on bitmap1 it starts activity1, and on touching bitmap2 it starts activity2.here is what i did in short,
Bitmap bimap1,bitmap2;

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {

        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 100, 100, paint);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 200, 200, paint);




        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `onClick` events for that, because its a higher abstraction. You are either clicked or not, you don't have much information. So you will have to go down to the `onTouchEvent` and process touch events to see if a tap/click happens, and where does it happens. Touch events specify its position in client coordinates, so they will be relative to the `(100,100)` and `(200,200)` you are using to draw in your `Canvas`. So basically you can match the touch event positions to the information in your `Canvas`.

Or alternatively, if your real use case is as simple as your example, you can use two different `View`s each holding one `Bitmap` and simply `setOnClickListener()` on each of them. You can use two `ImageView`s and reference the *bitmap drawables* directly from *XML* instead of `Draw`ing them yourself.

Comment: can you please give a little explain how to match the touch event positions to imformation.?

Comment: @Hello: You would get the touch position by using `getX()` and `getY()` and see if the point is within the rect that holds your bitmap

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `onTouch` event on the bitmap. you have two options now.

1) User two separate canvas in two separate view and bind `onTouch` event on them.

**OR**

2) Get coordinates of your bitmap and from this coordinates, decide which bitmap is selected.

For Ex: (Just a rough code to have some hint)

```
if (x >= xOfYourBitmap && x < (xOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getWidth())
                && y >= yOfYourBitmap && y < (yOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getHeight())) {
        //you are inside your bitmap
}
```

Comment: `onTouchEvent` is a method from `View`, not `Canvas`